# need help to revert back to default file permission magento2 aws

Tags: magento2, aws

After giving 777 permission website not working I think issue with file permission ,can you have a look ,let me know what to do next to bring back to default permission Installed on aws ,rds,

[image: file permission]

Answer (score 0):

please run below command to set perfect permission for magento in root path.

so if your root path is /var/www/html then please go to that path by

```
cd /var/www/html/
```

and then run below command one by one

set all directory permission to 775

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

set all files permission to 664

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

so all files permission of var, generated, vendor, pub/static, pub/media, app/etc directory to g+w by below command

```
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
```

and all folder permission of var, generated, vendor, pub/static, pub/media, app/etc to g+ws.

```
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
```